# Redirecting URL With Token Parameter That Contains '+'

Tags: javascript, urlencode, x-www-form-urlencoded

I'm having issues creating a redirect to an URL from an API that I'm using within my application.  I request a `session token` which is used in the redirect URL, but I experience issues when the token contains a `+` in it.  My guess is that the browser is picking this up as a `space` instead of an actual token character which is causing the redirect to fail ever so often.

Here is an example token that can come back from a request to the API: `1w5OX65MRj+3J9R5AXjMWQLAAXIo5TXa`

Looking at the network tab I see that it tries to request the redirect with this token instead:
`1w5OX65MRj 3J9R5AXjMWQLAAXIo5TXa`, which would be why it's causing issues.

I tried replacing the `+` with `%2B` but it seems like my application isn't replacing it at all which is a little odd to me.

Here is my code:

```
let token = "";

        $.get('/_token_req', {contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, (response) => {
            //console.log(response);
            token = response;
            token = token.replace(/\+/g, "%2B");  // this doesn't replace the + character for some reason

            $.get('/_redirect', {token: response}, (response) => {
                //console.log(response);
                if(response == "OK"){
                    window.location.href = "https://someapi/payments/?auth_token=" + token;
                }
            })
        })
```

I don't know much about URL encoding, but if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be super helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Err, `%2B` is hex for a `+`.  But the `+` is a stand in for a space in the url, which is a `%20` hex.

Comment: @Taplar So I should be using ```%20``` instead??

Comment: I would expect that would be the case.

Comment: @Taplar I will give this a try.

Comment: @Taplar it looks like even after replacing it this way that it is still being treated as a space in the network tab.  It replaces it within the URL correctly but it's still treating it like before when using it to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues with your code:

One that you need to use `encodeURIComponent` to encode any symbols in your token so that it can be sent in appropriate manner.

Two, while calling the second request `$.get('/_redirect'`, you didn't use the `replace`d token but the simple `response` that you received from earlier request.

Change your code to this to eliminate both errors:

```js
        let token = "";

        $.get('/_token_req', {contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, (response) => {
            token = encodeURIComponent(response);

            $.get('/_redirect', {token: token}, (response) => {
                if(response == "OK"){
                    window.location.href = "https://someapi/payments/?auth_token=" + token;
                }
            })
        })
```

Comment: I will give this a shot.